# asp.net dynamic theme changing

Tags: asp.net, stylesheet

In my asp.net application every user must can to change the theme or skin of the page and it's content such as header image,back ground image ,back color and ... in his/her admin page.
the number of users is unlimited and hierarchically  then i can not create some pr-edefault theme or skin for application and set the Theme Property in the PreRender event.
what is you suggestion for this scenario?

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14505/Dynamic-Themes-in-ASP-NET-2-0-C

Comment: Dear joe! please read my question again! i say i can not define pre-default themes that user can select one of them.i already saw the link which you provide.at the link the pre-default themes where defined and the name of the theme read from data base.this is not thing which i want.

Comment: sounds like you need to use Profile and set background color, image, etc on a per user basis http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163724.aspx